# How to split the content inside key

Tags: python, dictionary

Dictionary is below

```
my = [('a','/home/ma'),('a','/home/mk')]
```

My code:

```
{b:a for a,b in my }
```

My Output:

```
{'/home/ma': 'a', '/home/mk': 'a'}
```

Expected output:

```
{'ma': 'a', 'mk': 'a'}
```

Comment: Do you have a general idea how you'd get from `'/home/ma'` to `'ma'` and you just don't know how to do it in the key part of a dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `b: a` in your code with `os.path.split(b)[-1]: a` or, more cleanly (as per @BearBrown comment), `os.path.basename(b): a`(you also need to `import os`).

```
import os

my = [('a','/home/mak'),('a','/home/mk')]

{os.path.basename(b): a for a, b in my}
# {'mak': 'a', 'mk': 'a'}
```

Comment: I know this is a simple use-case, but for the sake of it: It might be better to use `pathlib` than `os.path` when dealing with paths. This can be achieved with `Path('/home/mk').name`

Answer (score 1):

`{b.split('/')[2]:a for a,b in my }`

Or if you always want last slash

```
{list(reversed(b.split('/')))[0]:a for a,b in my}
```

Comment: `b.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]`…